# max-width seems not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'll be only including the fiddle since its a long code (apologies since I included the whole code), my problem here is only in safari the two columns are not taking the full width which is `800px`. Everything works fine in other browsers. I tried using `width: 100%;` but then the margin-right get discarded. Also I think I can use something like `width: 97%`, but there must some other workaround. Please help, thanks in advance!

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/RqDLs/2/)

Below is the results in Safari vs firefox.

---

Safari
[image: This is what I'm getting in safari.]

---

Firefox

[image: firefox]

Answer (score 1):

Add `width: 97.5%;` (780px) to your `#main-content-wrapper` and remaining 1.25% (10px margin on each side) which makes it to total of `800px`. Because when you define `width: 100%;` (it will take the whole 800px) and the additional margin, padding will be sacrifised on the right side. Look at this **[**link*](http://jsfiddle.net/RqDLs/6/)***

I have added 5% padding and it's also getting sacrifised on the right side while it remains intact on the left side. It's a CSS rule.

[**SEE THE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RqDLs/5/)

```
#main-content-wrapper {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 97.5%;
    margin: 1.25%;
}
```

Comment: actually the problem is not on that specific media query, its actually in the first style on the css part. Try to increase the `column-count` under `.main-content`, the width stays the same.

Comment: then when the width drops below 800px, the margin right is discarded. Border on the right hand side becomes invisible.

Comment: @vephelp you have calculate the margin in % and apply it accordingly and you can't make the width 100% too because when you do that, it takes up the whole 800px and the margin is sacrifised on the right side. It's a CSS rule. Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/RqDLs/6/ I have added 5% padding and it's also getting sacrifised on the right side while it remains intact on the left side.

Comment: Actually this solved my problem so I am grateful. I had an image with max-width:400px and on a mac it kept ignoring the max width. So I put in after the max-width  width:100% and now Safari is obeying my max width.

Answer (score 0):

It works with Safari 5.1. The max-width property in CSS is used to set the maximum width of a specified element. The max-width property overrides the width property, but min-width will always override max-width whether followed before or after width in your declaration